# desplegar una lista si se escoge una opcion ionic

Tags: ionic, formularios, lista

estoy realizando una aplicacion en ionic3 para realizar un ingreso de horas por area de trabajo (unidad), donde existen varios proyectos por area (unidad), lo que quiero realizar es que al momento de selecciona una unidad, unicamente se me habiliten los proyectos para esa unidad, estuve revisando la opcion *ngif que trabaja con condicionantes pero no me permite colocar una de las opciones para la unidad que quiero seleccionar, este es mi codigo ya que al momento me despliega todos los proyectos para todas las unidades. 
si alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionar esto se lo agradeceria mucho

```
<ion-content padding>
<form (ngSubmit)="onAddTarea(f.value)" #f="ngForm">
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Nombre de la unidad</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="unidad" multiple="false" name="unidad">  
        <ion-option>Unidad 1</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Unidad 2</ion-option>
        <ion-option>Unidad 3</ion-option>    
      </ion-select>

    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Nombre del proyecto</ion-label>

        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="proyecto" multiple="false" name="proyecto">
          <ion-option>Proyecto 1 unidad 1</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 2 unidad 1</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 3 unidad 1</ion-option>
        </ion-select>

        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="proyecto" multiple="false" name="proyecto">
          <ion-option>Proyecto 1 unidad 2</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 2 unidad 2</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 3 unidad 2</ion-option>
        </ion-select>

        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="proyecto" multiple="false" name="proyecto">
          <ion-option>Proyecto 1 unidad 3</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 2 unidad 3</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 3 unidad 3</ion-option>
        </ion-select>

    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
</ion-list>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un (ionChange) ligado a una función para detectar los cambios al select de unidades y los *ngIf en cada select del proyecto

```
<ion-content padding>
<form (ngSubmit)="onAddTarea(f.value)" #f="ngForm">
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Nombre de la unidad</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="unidad" multiple="false" name="unidad" (ionChange)="mostrarOpciones($event)" >  
        <ion-option value="unidad1">Unidad 1</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="unidad2">Unidad 2</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="unidad3">Unidad 3</ion-option>    
      </ion-select>

    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Nombre del proyecto</ion-label>

        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="proyecto" multiple="false" name="proyecto" *ngIf="mostrarProyecto1">
          <ion-option>Proyecto 1 unidad 1</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 2 unidad 1</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 3 unidad 1</ion-option>
        </ion-select>

        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="proyecto" multiple="false" name="proyecto" *ngIf="mostrarProyecto2">
          <ion-option>Proyecto 1 unidad 2</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 2 unidad 2</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 3 unidad 2</ion-option>
        </ion-select>

        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="proyecto" multiple="false" name="proyecto" *ngIf="mostrarProyecto3">
          <ion-option>Proyecto 1 unidad 3</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 2 unidad 3</ion-option>
          <ion-option>Proyecto 3 unidad 3</ion-option>
        </ion-select>

    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
</ion-list>
</form>
```

En tu component.ts agrega variables de visibilidad para cada ion-select (los del ngIf) y la función "mostrarOpciones" debe hacer el trabajo.

```
//imports...

export class UnidadesPage{

    mostrarProyecto1:boolean = false;
    mostrarProyecto2:boolean = false;
    mostrarProyecto3:boolean = false;

    constructor() {}

    mostrarOpciones(unidad:string){
        switch(unidad){
            case 'unidad1':
                this.mostrarProyecto1 = true;
                if(this.mostrarProyecto2) this.mostrarProyecto2 = false ;
                if(this.mostrarProyecto3) this.mostrarProyecto3 = false ;
                break;
            case 'unidad2':
                this.mostrarProyecto2 = true;
                if(this.mostrarProyecto1) this.mostrarProyecto1 = false ;
                if(this.mostrarProyecto3) this.mostrarProyecto3 = false ;
                break;
            case 'unidad3':
                this.mostrarProyecto3 = true;
                if(this.mostrarProyecto2) this.mostrarProyecto2 = false ;
                if(this.mostrarProyecto1) this.mostrarProyecto1 = false ;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```